# localhost not fetching data from pgadmin tables

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to fetch PostgreSQL table data from localhost. Strange here because those tables I migrated from the pyCharm Django project.

[pgAdmin is filled with tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gswep.png)

Not sure what went wrong, I double check my setting.py file and database is configured correctly `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql'` along with DB name, username, password etc. also, /etc/paths have these paths.

[paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtZ6j.png)

Please let me know if any information needed.

*I am using Mac OS V10.14.2*

Comment: What exactly is not working? Did you specify the correct hostname?

Comment: `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'` is assigned to databases, and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
I have some customers and reviews in tables and but even after running `services.update_customers()` won't displaying customers in the local environment. 
web services are written on services.py

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and I thought it will be helpful to others if someone has the same issue.

Since data was migrated from the local project, extract a PostgreSQL database into a script file using `pg_dump [database_name] > [outfile.sql]`.

The .sql file created by pg_dump is and is intended to be read in by the psql program. The general command form to restore a dump is `psql [database_name] < [outfile.sql]`

Documentation for migrating data: https://postgresapp.com/documentation/migrating-data.html

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html